# Do you have to cancel requestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe

I am using following snippet from Paul Irish:

```
// requestAnimationFrame shim & fallback
window.requestAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();
```

I also saw a polyfill but I did not tested this shim in all browsers yet, so I am unsure wether I will need polyfill or not. Perhaps I won't, saving file size.

I am wondering do I actually need to call `cancelAnimationFrame` somewhere and if so, guess I would need another shim for it. Something like reversed of above:

```
// cancelAnimationFrame shim & fallback
window.cancelAnimFrame = (function () {
    return window.cancelAnimationFrame || window.webkitCancelAnimationFrame || window.mozCancelAnimationFrame || function (callback) {
        window.clearTimeout(callback);
    };
})();
```

Basically I tried to `console.log` the function that is running within `requestAnimationFrame` and I can see when logging stops so I guess animation frame is no longer used...

My function `step()` is ending like this:

```
if (progress == 1) return;

requestAnimFrame(step);
```

I really care about this and I am still learning about animations overall. 
It was painful to create animation for me especially using easing equations. Straight answer will do just fine and if needed to cancel please show me an example how ? Right now I believe that cancelAnimationFrame is used only for manual canceling or some complex animations. Well it's just what I think, I am not sure yet.

Comment: why do you call the cancel function with the same name again `window.requestAnimFrame`? is it a typo?

Comment: Each drawn object might be independent and be hooked directly to rAF. If an object is removed another object responsible might cancel its rAF to 'kill' him. Both ideas are stupid : rAF's overhead is big, so much better draw everything in a single handler.  And removal by cAF method is hacky. Well, no use !!

Comment: I do that in a single handler of course. Well alright, thank you for your comment!

Comment: well second thought if a blur or resize event is raised then you might want the game to stop even before the next frame. Don't know if a user might notice that in any way. I suspect blur to cancel rendering at once, so there would be no effect. I'll test this tomorrow  !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cancelAnimationFrame` is used to stop an animation from outside the animation function. In your `step()` example, you're stopping the animation from inside the animation function. Both are viable, but the internal stop is probably more common.

The main reason you would want to use `cancelAnimationFrame` is if you don't want to take animation cycles calculating when you should stop your animation. If you had multiple cases that could stop an animation, checking each case inside the animation loop is actually less performant than calling `cancelAnimationFrame` when you set the condition to be true somewhere else.

As an example, let's say that you wanted to stop your animation when `progress == 1` as in your example, but `progress` only get's set to one when the user pauses the game. Since users don't pause the game very often, you're actually wasting clock cycles looking at the variable each frame (even if it's only a few ms). If you also had to check if the user died (`progress == 2`), or jumped to the main menu (`progress == 3`), then you would be checking 3 if statements every frame. Since you would already have code that checks for these conditions outside of the animation loop, calling `cancelAnimationFrame` when the code is run helps your animations run slightly faster.

Comment: I understand. Thank you for providing this answer. It is exactly what I was thinking...